# Java JPA - prevent usage of zero-argument constructor of Embedded ID class

Tags: java, jpa

I have some JPA class for persistance

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public MyJPA
{
  @EmbeddedId
  private MyJpaPrimaryKey key;

  @Column(name = "DATABASE_COLUMN")
  private SomeType someData;

  ...
}
```

And the Class for the primary key

```
@Embeddable
public class MyJpaPrimaryKey
{
  ...
}
```

Both have constructors with all required fields and/or whatever is convenient.

Now, JPA forces some zero-argument constructors

- The Java class for mapped type "MyJpa" must define a non-private zero-argument constructor
- Embedded ID class *(i.e. `MyJpaPrimaryKey`)* should include a zero argument constructor

None of those zero-argument constructors are meant for explicit use. I understand that I can make `MyJpa() { }` package private, so JPA is happy, and no-one else will use it unintentionally. But `MyJpaPrimaryKey() { }` must be `public`.

How do I prevent someone from using the zero-argument constructor `MyJpaPrimaryKey()`? In case this is not possible, how to get a warning (or better error) if someone uses it? I can think of `@Deprecated` annotation, but this feels like misusing this annotation.

Comment: You could throw a runtime exception (e.g. UnsupportedOperationException) inside the constructor...but that will probably break JPA.

Comment: @BillHorvath - yes, that will break JPA